# GPIO sysfs no input or output change

Tags: gpio, sysfs

I can successfully export a GPIO pin, set both input and output directions and change the value, and apparently read in an input.
But, I’m not able to monitor the GPIO change input or output state

When I enable the GPIO sysfs, the result of `# cat sys/kernel/debug/gpio` is `GPIO 206-255`

.
I wrote a C program to enable each pin successively, and these were the following that were able to export:

> 207, 212, 213, 214, 216, 218, 220, 223, 224, 226, 228, 230, 233, 234,
>   242, 243, 244, 245 & 254.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5368870/gpiosysfs.jpg
[image]

Afterwards, I assigned each of the pins as an output, and attempt to toggle it.  My test board has the all GPIO pins wired out to a breadboard with a +5V and GND supplying power to a transistor with an LED and the GPIO pin feeding into the base through appropriate sized resistor. As I changed the output value of any GPIO pin, my test circuit remains unchanged.  I have also configured each pin as an input and fed in 5V and again, no changed in the read value.

I’m running Linux 3.10.18 on an Advantech SBC.
http://www.advantech.com/products/1-2JKD1I/PCM-9389/mod_622b1bb4-6d15-4be3-bb88-d20fe6736a1c.aspx

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Did you test the pins with a multimeter?

Comment: Yes.  Multimeter output voltage is same as LED display, it's always 5V.